# Disable SSLCompression in Apache <2.2.24 in Gentoo

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, gentoo

Thanks a lot beforehand. I need to disable SSL Compression in Apache 2.2.16 in Gentoo in order to mitigate TLS CRIME. I've been searching for a long time and I've found out that it's possible to disable SSL Compression in old versions of Apache in CentOS by adding `export OPENSSL_NO_DEFAULT_ZLIB=1` to the file `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. However, I need to do the same in Gentoo, but obviously I don't have the file `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.

Do you know some way to do so?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you describe for CentOS effectively sets an environment variable during Apache httpd start-up. You can probably set such a variable  by editing the start-up script  `/etc/init.d/apache2` and including it there or check that script if it loads environment settings from a similar file to ` /etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Comment: It's Gentoo, of course, so just update Apache (and world).